# WMS Server connecting to Tableau Server?

Tags: tableau-api, wms

I am a bit confused on how the process of mapping works on Tableau. I understand that you are able to connect to multiple WMS servers through the desktop client but what happens once you publish it onto the Tableau server?

Does the "publish" include all the map details needed for Tableau Server to display to viewers?.. or does the Tableau server need a connection to the WMS servers that were connected from the desktop?

Comment: Generally speaking, you have two options, you can publish an extract of the data where everything relevant will be packaged up and uploaded so the end user can explore (faster), or you can publish a connection to the data source itself, allowing greater flexibility with live data, but slower.

Comment: @BenP , In regards to Databases I agree with you but I am not sure if that is true with WMS.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, I believe it depends on the WMS service you use.

In our shop we have integrated with Mapbox (I'm not affiliated with them). As long as you save your Mapbox API Key in the twb file, Mapbox works fine when you publish. We have not found any issues once published.

We also tried Google Maps. With published workbooks, we had some issues with the firewall (easily fixed) as well as issues with the mapping service blocking us (we were using a free account). Because we found Mapbox, we did not pursue Google Maps. Because we had to put in an exception in our firewall, I'm assuming it does not upload any images or maps and makes live calls to the map server.

Comment: Neither Mapbox or Google maps are WMS